# Image upload crop resize using jquery and servlet

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins, servlets

I am developing a web application where the user has to upload the pics.Is their any widget or plugin to upload a image to the store in the data base and display the same image in a given box, I am using jquery html5 in the front end and serlvet and my sql at the back end. I will very happy if I get image resizer and crop option along.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://www.codeforest.net/how-to-crop-an-image-using-jquery-and-php

That might be of some use to you, they show a preview to the user and let them crop the image also.